# How to add bookmarks(URL) on the home screen for android

Tags: android

I have tried adding a bookmark on the home screen manually. Need some help on doing it programatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me -
Add to permission to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Use the following code:

```
    public void createGoogleSearchShortcut(Context context) {
    String urlStr = String.format(context.getString(R.string.homescreen_shortcut_search_url), context.getString(R.string.app_id));
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlStr));
    // shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    // Sets the custom shortcut's title
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, context.getString(R.string.search));
    // Set the custom shortcut icon
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

    // add the shortcut
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);

}
```

Please note: I strongly suggest asking the user before adding the bookmark. Adding bookmarks to his home screen without his permission is "not polite"...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by bookmark. Maybe this tutorial could help?

https://web.archive.org/web/20200210093614/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/04/open-urlwebsite-from-android.html

This is an application that starts up the browser pointing to a web page. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but what I have in mind is there is a bookmark placed in your homescreen and you can launched the website from there. If you open your browser in android and go to bookmarks, you can actually place a shortcut of that bookmark to your homescreen. Any more ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the (poorly documented) action [INSTALL_SHORTCUT](http://chdorner.com/2011/01/02/android-how-to-add-home-screen-shortcuts-to-your-app/). You'll need the respective permission, as explained in that link